# webkit-animation-duration JQuery speed adjustment

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically change the speed of my animation. The dynamic change works in all browsers except Chrome. The animation works in Chrome when it is static.

**CSS**

```
.move{
    -webkit-animation-name: marqueeTop;
        animation-name:marqueeTop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
        animation-duration: 30s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-direction:normal;
        animation-direction:normal;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
        animation-iteration-count:1;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
setDuration(Seconds);

function setDuration(Seconds) {
    //changes the durantion 
    $(move).css({
        "-webkit-animation-duration": Seconds + 's',
            "animation-duration": Seconds + 's',
    });
}
```

Comment: How you get your **Seconds** ?

Comment: Is the `.css` called before any animation or afterwards?

Comment: @MartinErnst  Edited to show the whole function

Comment: Can you show what the inspector shows after you've run the setDuration function?

Comment: @JonasGrumann good call. It turns out all of the other animation setting I have in my CSS above were being disabled. So once I added duration, timing ...etc it worked